# amdgpu-pro installation failed and now dependencies problem

Tags: opencl, amd-gpu, ubuntu-20.10

first of all please bear with me as my English is still improving. So, yesterday i was trying to install DaVinci Resolve 16 on my newly installed Pop Os using an AMD RX 570 but i came across a problem related to openCL. So, i did some research and i found this command:

> sudo apt install mesa-opencl-icd

Once, I did that and started DaVinci it crashed on startup with error "DaVinci Resolve quit unexpectedly "

Again I came to google for help and i found that i need to install amdgpu-pro drivers to get my gpu openCL support and i followed these instructions:

```
* you need to edit the "amdgpu-pro-install"-file.

* Change the string "ubuntu" to debian or debianlinux or so.

* The string "ubuntu" you can find in function os_release()

* With Linux Mint i need to change it to "linuxmint" and installation will be fine
```

so I followed the instructions and now it is giving me these errors:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 amdgpu-dkms
 amdgpu
 amdgpu-pro-rocr-opencl
 amdgpu-pro
 amdgpu-pro-lib32

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and now i can't install or uninstall any pkg or deb file

```
-> sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
5 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up amdgpu-dkms (1:5.6.20.906316-1188099) ...
Removing old amdgpu-5.6.20.906316-1188099 DKMS files...

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 5.6.20.906316-1188099
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new amdgpu-5.6.20.906316-1188099 DKMS files...
Building for 5.8.0-7630-generic
Building for architecture amd64
Building initial module for 5.8.0-7630-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.8.0-7630-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-7630-generic (amd64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/amdgpu/5.6.20.906316-1188099/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-dkms (--configure):
 installed amdgpu-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of amdgpu:
 amdgpu depends on amdgpu-dkms (= 1:5.6.20.906316-1188099); however:
  Package amdgpu-dkms is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of amdgpu-pro-rocr-opencl:
 amdgpu-pro-rocr-opencl depends on amdgpu-dkms (= 1:5.6.20.906316-1188099); however:
  Package amdgpu-dkms is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-pro-rocr-opencl (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of amdgpu-pro:
 amdgpu-pro depends on amdgpu (= 20.45-1188099); however:
  Package amdgpu is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-pro (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of amdgpu-pro-lib32:
 amdgpu-pro-lib32 depends on amdgpu (= 20.45-1188099) | amdgpu-hwe (= 20.45-1188099No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
   No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                 No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                                     No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                           ); however:
  Package amdgpu is not configured yet.
  Package amdgpu-hwe is not installed.
 amdgpu-pro-lib32 depends on amdgpu-pro (= 20.45-1188099) | amdgpu-pro-hwe (= 20.45-1188099); however:
  Package amdgpu-pro is not configured yet.
  Package amdgpu-pro-hwe is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package amdgpu-pro-lib32 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 amdgpu-dkms
 amdgpu
 amdgpu-pro-rocr-opencl
 amdgpu-pro
 amdgpu-pro-lib32

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to uninstall amdgpu(-pro) drivers by running /usr/bin/amdgpu(-pro)-uninstall script.

Did you try to install the amdgpu drivers with the different kernel as advised [here](https://community.amd.com/t5/drivers-software/can-t-install-amdgpu-drivers-on-ubuntu-20-04-1-5-4-0-56-generic/m-p/427165#M134805)?